# SignalR Progress through MVC Controller

Tags: asynchronous, model-view-controller, signalr, iprogress

[image: Work Flow Scenario]

Above image represents the scenario I am trying to solve.

I know from my previous experience that the Progress reporting pattern can be used to solve the problem of keeping the client updated but back then client was communicating to the hub directly,  meaning there was no controller or code behind.

In the above image, the problem is that controller needs to do stuff before it can make call to the DB.

Also, the DB returns segments in the form of files, so I added an async filesystemwatcher for notifying me every time a response file gets created.

The goal is to keep feeding client browser with response segments as when you receive it, until we reach the end of responses.

The question is: how do I trigger the signalR Hub from controller / service methods and keep feeding responses to client browser?

UPDATE:

To narrow down the problem

1. My controller calls service method

   ```
   string contents = await    _logService. ResponseFileWaiterAsync         (myData.guid.ToString());
   ```
2. In the `ResponseFilewaiterAsync` method, when the first file gets created I trigger the hub

   ```
    BroadcastResponseToClient(responseFilePath, hubConnection);

        private void BroadcastResponseToClient(string responseFilePath, HubConnection hubConnection)
       {
           var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(typeof(string).Name);
           hubConnection
               .Start()
               .ContinueWith(_ => hub.Invoke("UpdateResponseToClient", ResponseHtml));
       }
   ```
3. The hub reports the responses to client as well as go look for next file until it is done

   ```
          public async Task UpdateResponseToClient(IProgress<string> progress,string filePath)
       {
           // Clients.Caller.appendReportToPage(ResponseHtml);

          string result = await _jbaseLoggingService.ResponseFileWaiterAsync(filePath);
           progress.Report(result);
       }
   ```

Problem: how to trigger a progress report hub from service method / controller? 
Where should I complete my request when it is done with updates – should it go back to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have solved my problem. First thing I had to do was to render a empty placeholder client, so that I could start my client side connection (hub connection) and then make a AJAX call to the actual controller method while sending in connection id to the controller.

1. Controller calls service method

   ```
   await  _logService.ResponseFileWaiterAsync(myData.guid.ToString(),clientId);
   ```
2. Service waits for filewatcher to notify about file created/renamed then reads the contents of the file and communicates it back to client with the help of clientId

   ```
    ResponseFileWaiterAsync(string responseFileName, string clientId)
    {
       //do stuff
       await DropFileHelper.WaitForResponseFileAsync(responseFilePath);
       contents = LoadResponseFile(responseFilePath);
       //do stuff
       Clients.Client(clientId).appendReportToPage(contents);
    }
   ```

Clients are loaded in the constructor using

```
Clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyResponseHub>().Clients;
```

appendReportToPage - is the client callback method

3. MyResponseHub is empty. All I needed was to make sure the SignalR has a hub to work through its magic

   ```
                         public class JbaseResponseHub : Hub
                           {
                           }
   ```

   4. Client side JS

```html
   $(function () {                   
        var _clientId;
        var hubProxy = $.connection.myResponseHub;        
        hubProxy.client.appendReportToPage = function (ResponseHtml) {
            // Add the message to the page.                 
            $('#responseBody').append( "<p>"+ResponseHtml+"</p>" + '</br></br></br>');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                //alert('in hub start');
                _clientId = $.connection.hub.id;
                console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
                //alert(_clientId);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/mycontroller/ProcessRequest',
                    data: { qs: $('#encryptedString').html().trim(), clientId: _clientId },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        
                    }
                });
            })
            .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });

});
```

Lessons learnt

- Client has to be rendered so that it can create connection with hub
- You can communicate to clients from service class / methods as long as you have access to the clients

Helpful links

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc